# Python: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

I have imported Python Project in Eclipse. When i run the script on mac machine i am getting error as below:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/noimac-mini4/Documents/workspace/MobileAutomationPy\\..\\..\\..\\..\\'`

what could be possible cause of error here?

Same project imported in windows machine and it is working fine but not in mac

Comment: Could you please provide the code here?

Comment: Your probably trying some relative path which does not exists, if yo'll provide the code and the full traceback it will easier to debug.

Comment: This is big project which i imported in eclipse BUT same code imported in windows machine working correctly.

Comment: @sandy Windows and Mac paths are different if you didn't pay attention and made a propper use with os.path functions then you can have mismatch

Answer (score 2):

What i see here is a lot of *backslashes* (`\`) in your path which are used on Windows platforms, that is why it works when imported on Windows machine. My guess would be that you have this path stored inside a string or something.

Better approach would be to use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) and `os.sep` when dealing with platform independent path's.